# Map possible paths for amount of moves C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am re-creating the game of cluedo and I want to map the possible paths that the player can move after dice roll.

I have mapped the grid by drawing pictureboxes and naming them to their mapped location.

Here is my code so far for the possible paths:

```
int Roll;
private void RollDice()
{
    ResetTiles();
    JimRandom Random = new JimRandom();

    //Roll DIce 1
    int dice1 = Random.Next(1, 7);
    //Roll DIce 2
    int dice2 = Random.Next(1, 7);

    Roll = dice1 + dice2;

    //Set Dice images
    pbDice1.BackgroundImage = Roller[dice1 - 1].Picture;
    pbDice2.BackgroundImage = Roller[dice2 - 1].Picture;

    btnRoll.Enabled = false;

    Test(Roll);

    //Show available moves
    Control[] lCurrent = PnlBoard.Controls.Find("pnl" + CurrentPlauer, true);
    Panel Current = null;
    System.Drawing.Point CurrentLoc = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    foreach (Control c in lCurrent)
    {
        Current = c as Panel;
        CurrentLoc = new System.Drawing.Point(c.Location.X, c.Location.Y);
    }

    //Dynamic map
    List<string> possiblities = new List<string>();
    int currentRow = CurrentLoc.Y / tileWidth;
    int currentCol = CurrentLoc.X / tileHeight;

    //Find all possible start blocks
    string down = String.Format("Col={0:00}-Row={1:00}", currentCol, currentRow + 1);
    string up = String.Format("Col={0:00}-Row={1:00}", currentCol, currentRow - 1);
    string left = String.Format("Col={0:00}-Row={1:00}", currentCol - 1, currentRow);
    string right = String.Format("Col={0:00}-Row={1:00}", currentCol + 1, currentRow);

    List<string> startBlocks = new List<string>();

    //See if down is available
    Control[] LPossible = PnlBoard.Controls.Find(down, true);
    if (LPossible.Length > 0)
    {
        startBlocks.Add(down);
    }

    //See if Up is available
    LPossible = PnlBoard.Controls.Find(up, true);
    if (LPossible.Length > 0)
    {
        startBlocks.Add(up);
    }

    //See if left is available
    LPossible = PnlBoard.Controls.Find(left, true);
    if (LPossible.Length > 0)
    {
        startBlocks.Add(left);
    }

    //See if right is available
    LPossible = PnlBoard.Controls.Find(right, true);
    if (LPossible.Length > 0)
    {
        startBlocks.Add(right);
    }

    //possiblilities 1
    foreach (string s in startBlocks)
    {
        Control[] lStarBlock = PnlBoard.Controls.Find(s, true);
        PictureBox startBlock = lStarBlock[0] as PictureBox;

        int sRow = startBlock.Location.Y / tileWidth;
        int sCol = startBlock.Location.X / tileHeight;

        //Rows
        for (int row = sRow; row < sRow + Roll; row++)
        {
            //Columns
            for (int col = sCol; col < sCol + Roll; col++)
            {
                possiblities.Add(String.Format("Col={0:00}-Row={1:00}", col, row));
            }
        }            
    }

    //Show possible moves
    foreach (string p in possiblities)
    {
        LPossible = PnlBoard.Controls.Find(p, true);
        if (LPossible.Length > 0)
        {
            PictureBox active = LPossible[0] as PictureBox;
            active.Image = Cluedo.Properties.Resources.TileActive;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        //else
        //{
        //    break;
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to show the possible tiles to wich the player can move and the code I have at the moment is flawd

Comment: That's a very broad question. Can you explain in more detail what's wrong with your code? What results do you expect and what results do you actually get?

Comment: If the player rolls 5, I want to map five places from the current location.
At the moment it either maps to far or too close

Comment: Well, for starters, that method is doing way too many things. Split it up into different methods, where each method only does one thing: one to roll the dice, one to determine all possible paths for a given start location and distance, and one that displays those locations. That should narrow down the problem. Then step through the pathfinding method with a debugger to see if you can find the problem. If you can't find it, create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it here.

Comment: Test Project added to :
https://github.com/Whitewolfza/Cluedo.git

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of things I would do different here. This is more of a Code Review post, but there's a solution to your problem at the end, and perhaps the rest can help you to improve the overall state of your code.

**Randomness**

You're creating a new random generator instance for every method call:

```
JimRandom Random = new JimRandom();
```

This often results in the same values being generated if the method is called in rapid succession. Perhaps that's why you're using a cryptographic RNG instead of a PRNG? A PRNG should be sufficient for a game like this, as long as you reuse it.

**Using the right types**

You're determining the current player location with the following code:

```
//Show available moves
Control[] lCurrent = PnlBoard.Controls.Find("pnl" + CurrentPlauer, true);
Panel Current = null;
System.Drawing.Point CurrentLoc = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
foreach (Control c in lCurrent)
{
    Current = c as Panel;
    CurrentLoc = new System.Drawing.Point(c.Location.X, c.Location.Y);
}
```

It looks like `CurrentPlauer` is a string. Creating a `Player` class that stores the name and current location of a player would make things much easier:

```
Point currentLocation = currentPlayer.Location;
```

**Splitting game logic from UI code**

You're checking for passable tiles by doing string lookups against controls:

```
string down = String.Format("Col={0:00}-Row={1:00}", currentCol, currentRow + 1);
// ...
Control[] LPossible = PnlBoard.Controls.Find(down, true);
if (LPossible.Length > 0)
{
    startBlocks.Add(down);
}
```

Normally a 2D array is used for tile maps like these, possible encapsulated in a `Tilemap` or `Map` class. This makes working with tiles more natural, as you can work in tile coordinates directly instead of having to translate between UI and tile coordinates. It also breaks up the code more cleanly into a game-logic and a UI part (the code in your post is impossible to test without UI):

```
// TileMap class:
public bool IsPassable(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= Width || y < 0 || y >= Height)
        return false;
    return tiles[x][y] != Tile.Wall;  // enum Tile { Wall, Ballroom, DiningRoom, Hall, ... }
}
// When called from your Board code:
if (map.IsPassable(currentLocation.X, currentLocation.Y + 1))
    startBlocks.Add(new Point(currentLocation.X, currentLocation.Y + 1));
```

**Reducing repetition**

As for checking all direct neighboring tiles, there's no need to repeat the same code 4 times:

```
// Let's make a utility function:
public static IEnumerable<Point> GetNeighboringPositions(Point position)
{
    yield return new Point(position.X - 1, position.Y);
    yield return new Point(position.X, position.Y - 1);
    yield return new Point(position.X + 1, position.Y);
    yield return new Point(position.X, position.Y + 1);
}
// In the Board code:
foreach (Point neighboringPosition in GetNeighboringPositions(currentPosition))
{
    if (map.IsPassable(neighboringPosition.X, neighboringPosition.Y))
        startBlocks.Add(neighboringPosition);
}
```

**Determining valid moves**

Finally, we get to the code that determines which tiles the current player can move to:

```
//possiblilities 1
foreach (string s in startBlocks)
{
    Control[] lStarBlock = PnlBoard.Controls.Find(s, true);
    PictureBox startBlock = lStarBlock[0] as PictureBox;

    int sRow = startBlock.Location.Y / tileWidth;
    int sCol = startBlock.Location.X / tileHeight;

    //Rows
    for (int row = sRow; row < sRow + Roll; row++)
    {
        //Columns
        for (int col = sCol; col < sCol + Roll; col++)
        {
            possiblities.Add(String.Format("Col={0:00}-Row={1:00}", col, row));
        }
    }            
}
```

What this does is checking a rectangular area, using a starting position as its top-left corner. It's doing so for up to 4 neighboring positions, so the rectangles will partially overlap each other. That's just not going to work. If the map didn't have any obstacles, something like this, combined with a Manhattan distance check, could work (if you don't forget to look to the left and upwards too). Or better, some fancy looping that checks a diamond-shaped area.

However, you've got walls to deal with, so you'll need a different approach. The player's current position is at distance 0. Its direct neighbors are at distance 1. Their neighbors are at distance 2 - except those tiles that are at a lower distance (the tiles that have already been covered). Any neighbours of tiles at distance 2 are either at distance 3, or have already been covered. Of course, wall tiles must be skipped.

So you need to keep track of what tiles have already been covered and what neighboring tiles you still need to check, until you run out of movement points. Let's wrap that up into a reusable method:

```
public List<Point> GetReachableTiles(Point currentPosition, int maxDistance)
{
    List<Point> coveredTiles = new List<Point> { currentPosition };
    List<Point> boundaryTiles = new List<Point> { currentPosition };
    for (int distance = 0; distance < maxDistance; distance++)
    {
        List<Point> nextBoundaryTiles = new List<Point>();
        foreach (Point position in boundaryTiles)
        {
            foreach (Point pos in GetNeighboringPositions(position))
            {
                // You may also want to check against other player positions, if players can block each other:
                if (!coveredTiles.Contains(pos) && !boundaryTiles.Contains(pos) && map.IsPassable(pos.X, pos.Y))
                {
                    // We found a passable tile:
                    coveredTiles.Add(pos);
                    // And we want to check its neighbors in the next 'distance' iteration, too:
                    nextBoundaryTiles.Add(pos);
                }
            }
        }
        // The next 'distance' iteration should check the neighbors of the current boundary tiles:
        boundaryTiles = nextBoundaryTiles;
    }
    return coveredTiles;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code review, but you are talking about classes that you have not explained.

Do you want me to map the board in a 2d array first?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, or you can modify the code I've posted to use your current board representation. That's all up to you, it's your game. ;)